# Can't rename/move file from an OS X application title bar anymore

Tags: preview, macos

I noticed this a while ago: I used to be able to click on the title bar of applications like Preview or TextEdit and rename or move the file opened at the moment. Now if I click on the title bar nothing happens.

[image]

Has this feature been removed in a recent update? Is there any way to reactivate it?

Comment: @patrix, I see you added the _el-capitan_ tag however why was it necessary to remove the version information?  While we now know by the tag what major version of OS X we no longer know what minor version.  There _are_ differences between minor versions.  Keeping the full version info in a question is not unreasonable and IMO should not have been removed as it always good, when possible and or applicable, to test issues in the specific version being used.

Comment: @user3439894 In most cases the detailed version number doesn't matter. If it should turn out that it does in this case, we can take it from the edit history and include it in the question again.

Comment: It's still there (at least here). Does it occur with all your files (in different directories) or only with some? Where are the files stored (local drive, iCloud, external drive)?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on finding a resolution, maybe by next week.  So far I have discovered this since I have been using this for a long time--simply going to the application title bar and clicking on the name and having a dialog box drop down, changing the name and hitting return.  (NO DROP DOWN MENU WITH RENAME IN IT>).  It stopped working recently and these are some of the facts:

1. It is not an application plist that controls it.  This renaming process happens with lots of apps.
2. It does not appear to be an error in the system files because I can create a new user and it works.
3. It is not a network thing because my wife's system still works while mine on the same network does not.
4. It seems that it is somewhere in my user files.

I have sent some files to Apple Care and will know next week if they can tell me what plist or parameters control this so I can fix them..